# wordpress in wamp lan doesn't load css

Tags: css

I use wordpress in a lan with wamp. I can correctly see the lan from client pcs. It works perfectly with non wordpress websites so i don't think it's a lan setting problem. Is there any particular setting i should set in wordpress? Actually, it loads correctly, but without JS and CSS.

UPDATE, here's how CSS and JS are loaded in the plugin:

```
function agenda_my_scripts() {
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    // datepicker
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-datepicker', plugins_url( 'sys/js/datepicker.js', dirname(__FILE__) ), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    // CSS
    wp_register_style( 'agenda_css', plugins_url( 'sys/css/style.css', dirname(__FILE__) ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'agenda_css' );
    // jQuery CSS
    wp_register_style( 'jquery_ui_css', plugins_url( 'sys/css/jquery-ui.css', dirname(__FILE__) ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery_ui_css' );
}
```

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','agenda_my_scripts');

Then the child theme have the classic configuration:

```
/*
Theme Name:   Theme name
Theme URI:    -
Description:  Description
Author:       Author
Author URI:   -
Template:     child_template
Version:      1.0
Tags:         -
Text Domain:  child_template
*/

@import url("../twentytwelve/style.css");
```

where 'template' and 'text domain' match folder's name.

Moreover, if i activate the child theme, it loads twentyfourteen!!

This is very weird...

Comment: It's obvious. You don't have the CSS/JS LAN - development kit - plugin for Wordpress;-) No just kidding. A guess would be that it is htacess-related or it's that simple that it points to incorrect css/js - file.

Comment: Locally it loads CSS/JS correctly, only via lan i get the problem...
What about your "htacess-related" guess?

Comment: Please show use how you load the js/css files in the header (in the WP-installation) and where the the actual js/css files is.

Comment: i've updated the code with the original question...

Comment: ok i solved it, or better: i solved the css/js issue but the child theme is still looking for twentyfourteen instead of twentytwelve...i'll post the solution to the main problem below

Answer (score 3):

finally i solved it...this was a very annoying problem!
just enter your db and change in wp_option:
- siteurl: from localhost server's lan ip
- home: from localhost server's lan ip

that's it! :)

Comment: Please explain your solution better, so other readers can understand and reproduce it.

Comment: how can i explain better than this? 1) access your db (ex. with phpmyadmin); 2) in table wp_option search for value 'siteurl' and change it from 'localhost' to your machine external ip (i can't know what is the ip); 3) do the same with the value 'home'. I don't know what else to say about this...

Comment: Your comment is better already than your answer text. :) An explanation how that changes the way WordPress behaves would be useful too.

Comment: What happens when you change it to 127.0.0.1 instead of your external ip? Also you can change this in the WP settings, no need to enter the database.

Comment: Yes, you can do this change via WordPress/Settings/General, however, throughout your content or theme, if you have *any* links containing "localhost" (for whatever reason) then you have to go through a process to change them. That process could be manually changing them in the database or in your code files.

Comment: Ultimately, it just boils down to a simple concept: If you develop your website locally, then you will need to change URLs when it comes time to go live. While developing you're using a local address, like "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", which works fine for you. The moment you start feeding that website out to the public, either through your computer acting as a server, or moving the website to another server, then you're going to have problems like this because your visitors' browser will try to load "http://localhost/mystyles.css" but unable to do so. There's nothing more to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this query in your sql console:

```
update wp_options
set option_value = '/'
WHERE option_name = 'home'
   OR option_name = 'siteurl'
```